# Windows 10: how to obtain, in another way, same results of Sysprep when it doesn't want to work

Tags: windows, deployment, sysprep, cloning

In my job, it often happens that I have to replicate a Windows 10 Pro installation, with certain softwares and certain configurations on it, on other computers. Now, usually I use Sysprep for generalizing the installation and replicate it on the other machines using a cloning utility. But, quite often, Sysprep doesn’t want to do its job showing errors that are very annoying and hard to try to fix and causing a lot of wasted time. So, I’m wondering if there is a workaround or a third-party tool that you can use for having the same results of using Sysprep and it would be truly exceptional (but not necessary) if this workaround or tool could offer also the oobe experience on reboot (put a user name and possword, accept or reject stuff and so on). I know that there was NewSID utility by Russinovich and that he said that there are no issues of simply cloning a Windows installation from a pc to another but, anyway, I prefer to do it in a correct manner.

Comment: What are the actual issues with sysprep?

Comment: They vary from time to time so without wasting time, I would like to avoid using Sysprep when it gives problems and use an alternative

Comment: The simple answer is that sysprep is made by the company that probably has the most insight into how Windows works and would probably be the company to provide what you're looking for. If it's about provisioning new machines there are other approaches for unattended installations.